# python motor offers fetch_next exception on aggregation

Tags: pymongo, tornado-motor

I'm having difficulty with Motor's aggregation function giving a `no fetch_next` exception

The code is

```
cursor = db[collection].aggregate(myPipeline, cursor = {} )

if (yield cursor.fetch_next):
    obj = bson.json_util.dumps(cursor.next_object())
    self.write(obj)
```

that burped up the following

> Exception: :'TracebackFuture' object
>   has no attribute 'fetch_next'

Then I tried the following that was found in a SO question

```
 cursor = yield motor.Op(db[collection].aggregate, x_query)
```

that offered the same exception.

Running the aggregate in Mongo shell produces a bonafide result

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "Adam",
        "num" : 110
    },
    {
        "_id" : "Argyle",
        "num" : 77
    },
    {
        "_id" : "Net Valley",
        "num" : 67
    },
    {
        "_id" : "Notts Farm",
        "num" : 64
    },
    {
        "_id" : "Sam's Place",
        "num" : 59
    },
    {
        "_id" : "Tilly",
        "num" : 58
    },
    {
        "_id" : "Xavier",
        "num" : 52
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

Motor has offered no such issue with `find` and `find_one. In fact, it works awesome otherwise.

Installation was done via `pip install motor` on Ubuntu.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, [the documentation](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_collection.html#motor.MotorCollection.aggregate) is wrong. "aggregate" returns a Future, and you must yield the Future to get a cursor:

```
cursor = yield db[collection].aggregate(myPipeline, cursor={})

if (yield cursor.fetch_next):
    obj = bson.json_util.dumps(cursor.next_object())
    self.write(obj)
```

I've assigned myself a ticket, [MOTOR-34](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MOTOR-34), to track this issue for the next release.

Comment: Hey thanks for the heads up. And thanks a lot for Motor. Its incredible. Im guessing that you only really need cursor.fetch_next once in an aggregation  (give that the results are within the result object of the first fetch)

Comment: Actually, if you're using MongoDB 2.6, and you pass the "cursor={}" argument with Motor, then the "aggregate" returns a real cursor that streams results to you, just like find() does. So fetch_next / next_object works the same for aggregation: fetch_next will fetch the next batch *occasionally*, when the current batch is exhausted (every 4MB of data). next_object() pops the next document out of the batch.

Comment: btw. just followed the advice and it seems that providing cursor is invalid  ('cursor', {})]) failed: unrecognized field "cursor

Comment: Removing the cursor {} gives me Exception: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>:'dict' object has no attribute 'fetch_next'

Comment: hm. mongo 2.4.9 alas.

Comment: got it. cursor contains the result in 2.4.9. will upgrade and then do the fetch_next() but for now that rocks. thanks